# launchd bash kinit not retrieving kerberos tickets

Tags: macos, bash, kerberos, launchd

I'm trying to automate my kerberos ticket renewal. The script below runs perfectly in terminal but however fails in Automator or Launchd.
Although the expect command returns without error no new ticket is obtained.
running klist will return an empty list

Any help appreciated

```
#!/bin/sh
expect -c 'spawn /usr/bin/kinit USER@DOMAIN; expect "password:" { send "<password>" ; interact} '
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
echo "obtained kerberos token"
else
echo "couldn't obtain kerberos token"
exit 1;
fi
exit 0
```

running in launchd the following output is logged

> USER@DOMAIN's password:
>   obtained kerberos token

---

solved by adding some timeout after the send command

```
expect -c 'spawn /usr/bin/kinit USER@DOMAIN; expect "password:" { send "<password>" ; interact}; sleep 5 '
```

---

note: as Samson mentions in his comment, having the password in a script file is a bad solution. I used it for testing only.
using key tab is the right way to do this in kerberos.

Comment: Does your script show the output when run by  launchd? if so does it say that it obtained the token and doesn't? Please clarify  your question.

Comment: I added the output above. It looks like the script runs, enters the password and returns successfully. however no token is obtained.

Comment: Could you added a check for the token after it completes successfully and add it to the output to see if it actually is getting the token but, something is happening after the fact?

Comment: I've added the klist command. Logs show it returns empty - so no token is obtained during script runtime.

Comment: Is launchd running as a different user than you are when you execute without issue?

Comment: it's running under the same user. I specified the user explicitly

Comment: have you looked at your syslog to see if there is a difference when executing

Comment: finally I managed to solve this. thanks for the syslog hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding a timeout to the expect command worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Stuffing a hard-coded, clear-text password to a command prompt is an **evil** thing to do. Why use Kerberos authentication in the first place??

The expected way to create a Kerberos TGT in the background is to use a **keytab** (i.e. a file containing an encrypted "hash" of the password).

1. check your `krb5.conf` for the list of expected/supported encryptions (e.g. `aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`, `rc4-hmac`)
2. create the keytab with the `ktutil` utility *(read a tutorial first,
   the commands are far from intuitive)*
3. test with `kinit -kt /some/path/to/mykt.keytab`
4. restrict privileges on the keytab file because it would allow anyone
   to log in with your account

Comment: sure. should have mentioned that my question was for testing only. Switched to key tab in between. might have been easier right away but still wanted to get the expect command running properly.